# Grafana + Graphite: sum over time, with static beginning of time range

Tags: graphite, grafana

I am using Grafana with Graphite.

I have a metric for tickets that changed state to Closed. Applying integral() and keepLastValue() I am able to plot the current Closed tickets. As integral() resets (starts at zero) on the left side of the graph I only get the Closed tickets for the defined time period. I also need previous Closed tickets.

For instance, if there were 5 closed tickets in day 1, when ploting the closed tickets for day 2 (time range from: day 2 midnight), I want those 5 tickets to be accounted.

Is there some way to acomplish this with Grafana and Graphite?

Thanks.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, you can not do what you are suggesting. If your query time range is `NOW-24h`, then that is all the data you will be returned. You will have no context of any previous values; to accurately solve this, you would need to query all history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than storing a 1 for each ticket that's closed and using `integral()`, store the total number of closed tickets every minute.

That way you already have the data in the form you need for the graph you want.

To generate a graph that shows the ticket close activity you'd then use `derivative()`.